# CSR Certificate Azure Web App?

Tags: azure, web-applications, server, middleware, csr

I have a middleware server (A), under an Azure Web App role.
I'm using some SOAP service from a private server (B), a third party, that filters incoming IPs, so if my request IP is not registered in their firewall, I won't be able to access any information.

The middleware is not exclusive for (B) and a lot of other clients(C) request information from (A), including mobile devices (D).
I want to make sure that any request from (A) to (B) is accepted even if my current Request IP changes - and it will since the middleware is on the cloud and some changes are performed periodically -.
I had in mind a CSR certificate so that server (B) knows it's my Middleware (A), without caring for my request IP.

Is that idea a good choice?, am I missing something? are there any better solutions, recommendations?, I want to be able to connect (A) & (B) without affecting a lot (C) & (D).

**Note:** If the original idea works, where should I start to implement it, given the azure Web App constraints and private server ones?.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking how to authenticate to this private server (B).  There are many ways to handle this.  There is one big question...Do you have control over this private server?

If so, you have a slew of options; basic auth, cert auth, flavors of OAuth, etc.  pick one.  Make sure the transport is secure via SSL though.

You make it sounds like you don't have access, at which point you are at the mercy of this 3rd party.  IP restrictions can be put in place to try to limit exposure when a authentication mechanism can't be added.  I guess sometimes even both for those uber least-privilege types.  If they have IP filters in place, it is likely those will be difficult to remove, especially if they have other consumers of this SOAP service.

Also, a CSR is only the start of a certificate creation.  You can create on if you are going to use the Client Certificate auth option.  Or if you need to purchase a cert to secure the transport your middleware services.  However, it has nothing to do with authentication directly.